# QThreads interruption with slots and signals

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt4, qt-signals

I have a class which contains `QThread`. In the initialization function of this class the thread should be started. This works correct. in the thread there I have a `while(bool certainCondition){}` this `certainCondition` should be changed by a signal/slot connection.

The problem is that during the while is running the signal/slot is not opened.

Comment: could you post some code to show how exactly 'signal/slot is not opened'?

Comment: You need just to wait for a specific condition? i think [QWaitCondition](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwaitcondition.html)  can be useful here.

Answer (score 3):

You are not running an event loop in your thread, or you are blocking for a long time in your while-loop. Your slot cannot be called until you have returned control to the event loop, which will happen **after** you have finished the while-loop.

As a workaround, you can try calling [QCoreApplication::processEvents()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) inside your while-loop.

Answer (score 1):

In order for signals/slots to work across threads, the event loop must run.
If you use a while loop, the event loop is never run, and hence signals are not received.
This is how you normally run the event loop:

```
void Thread::run()
{
    ...do something
    exec();  //<<this runs the event loop
}
```

Now, your problem is that you want continuously run some code until some condition is met. In the above code, this won't work, because of the `exec()` call.
There are 2 possibilities to solve that (depending on what you want to achieve in your loop):

1. Use a QTimer, that fires let's say every 5 seconds, and calls a slot which executes your repeating code.
2. Use a QWaitCondition to check for a certain condition to be fulfilled; but then you cannot use signals and slots; instead you have to trigger the QWaitCondition.